# Leetcode permutations question in Java! How do the lists work in this question?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<List<Integer>> permutations = new LinkedList<>();
    permutations.add(new ArrayList<>());

    for(int currentNumber : nums){
        int n = permutations.size();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            List<Integer> oldPermutation = permutations.poll();
            for(int j=0; j<=oldPermutation.size(); j++){
        List<Integer> newPermutation = new ArrayList<Integer>(oldPermutation);
                newPermutation.add(j, currentNumber);
                if(newPermutation.size()==nums.length){
                    result.add(newPermutation);
                } else{
                    permutations.add(newPermutation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

In the bolded line **List newPermutation = new ArrayList(oldPermutation);**

Why do we pass in oldPermutation and what exactly does the () do in Java lists.

`Queue<List<Integer>> permutations = new LinkedList<>()` What does this line do. Is it a regular list
like [1,2,3] or a linked list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are defining a Queue with LinkedList. They are specific methods/operations that would work with these data structures in Java.
- For your second question, the desired data structure for the output is a List of List. You are successfully generating that using `oldPermutation`, then using `newPermutation` you are adding the current element. Finally, we are pushing that in the `result`, once it would reach the desired size (which is based on the `if` statement).

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkedList<List<Integer>> permutations = new LinkedList<>();
        permutations.add(new ArrayList<>());

        for (int currentNumber : nums) {
            int n = permutations.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                List<Integer> oldPermutation = permutations.poll();

                for (int j = 0; j <= oldPermutation.size(); j++) {
                    List<Integer> newPermutation = new ArrayList<>(oldPermutation);
                    newPermutation.add(j, currentNumber);

                    if (newPermutation.size() == nums.length)
                        result.add(newPermutation);

                    else
                        permutations.add(newPermutation);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the LeetCode's solution to the problem, you're trying to solve:

```
class Solution {
    public void backtrack(int n,
                          ArrayList<Integer> nums,
                          List<List<Integer>> output,
                          int first) {
        // if all integers are used up
        if (first == n)
            output.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(nums));

        for (int i = first; i < n; i++) {
            // place i-th integer first
            // in the current permutation
            Collections.swap(nums, first, i);
            // use next integers to complete the permutations
            backtrack(n, nums, output, first + 1);
            // backtrack
            Collections.swap(nums, first, i);
        }
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        // init output list
        List<List<Integer>> output = new LinkedList();

        // convert nums into list since the output is a list of lists
        ArrayList<Integer> nums_lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int num : nums)
            nums_lst.add(num);

        int n = nums.length;
        backtrack(n, nums_lst, output, 0);
        return output;
    }
}
```

---

You can use other types of data structures, depending on how you would like to solve the problem, such as with HashSet:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        backtrack(res, new ArrayList<>(), new HashSet<>(), nums);
        return res;
    }

    private void backtrack(List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> tempList, Set<Integer> tempSet, int[] nums) {
        if (tempSet.size() == nums.length) {
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>(tempList)));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (tempSet.contains(nums[i]))
                continue;
            tempSet.add(nums[i]);
            tempList.add(nums[i]);
            backtrack(res, tempList, tempSet, nums);
            tempSet.remove(tempList.get(tempSet.size() - 1));
            tempList.remove(tempList.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

- Maybe read through [these basics](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/).

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.
- [46. Permutations](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/)
- [46. Permutations - Discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/discuss/)